# How do I Re-enable INTERNET premission?

Tags: applications, permissions

I have an app where I disabled internet permission. Now I couldn't enable it again, while previous times I could. This may be the result of updating the app. I have root. How do I re-enable internet in this app again?

'Permission Pilot'(the app) doesn't seem to help.

Comment: How did you disable internet access for this app? Some vendors (I know of Xiaomi and OnePlus) offer "disabling internet access" per app as an option in Settings app of the device. Did you use that? If not, did you use a VPN/Iptables-based firewall app? We need details of the process. Also, which app is it? Provide us a play store link.

Comment: The app is Threema libre, I disabled it in the Settings app, under 'data' use. Now this app is no longer visible there.

Comment: Could you provide a link from where you downloaded this app?

Comment: I followed the instructions from here: https://threema.ch/en/faq/libre_installation . I don't think that that will help you, tough

Comment: If it has no data usage anymore, it cannot show up there, right. Have you tried *Settings › apps* (might nedd to togle it to show "all apps"), scroll to the app, open its entry, and check its "permissions" from there? Next to "permissions" there's also an entry for "mobile data and WiFi" which looks the same as where you disabled access. In the menu where you disabled it, you can also select a different time frame at the top (choose one before you disabled access for Threema) so it should show up again (indeed I see "Allow network access" there next to WiFi and "mobile data").

Comment: selecting a different time frame is not something I could do now